# How to Change text on Canvas prediodically

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can i draw a canvas with Image and Text where text is updated with new values periodically.
The problem i face is that the new text is writing on the old text without clearing it.

```
<canvas id="product1" width="184" height="239"/>
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width,img.height,0, 0, 184, 239);
context.font = "20pt Calibri";
context.textAlign="center"; 
context.fillText("Product 1",150,120);  
};
img.src = "https://image.ibb.co/gWNAoa/KEG.jpg";


setInterval(function() {
            var context = document.getElementById('product1').getContext("2d").fillText(Math.random(),150,120); 

        }, 2000);
```

Comment: clear canvas before filling text using : context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

Comment: That will also clear Image from canvas.

Comment: I will suggest third-party JS framework like `fabricjs` to do that

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear canvas, redraw image and draw new text.

Or if you know the place of the text, clear only the rect where text is and draw new text.

Use `clearRect(x,y,width,height)`

Canvas is like a paper where you have magic pencil that can write upon what you have drawn. You can't select particular object like line, text, rect, image or whatever you have drawn. You can just clear and write.

Comment: Can i retain the image without making http call everytime ? to clear and redraw the image and text on canvas again

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, the only idea of code design i have to achieve what you need is to create img tag in DOM with display:none and load your image from the dom.

It can be a temp solution before finding a better solution (if it exist)